# Can't connect device to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, device-driver

I had Android Studio set up on another machine and it was working without issue. Now, I have changed machines and my device will not connect. I downloaded and installed the USB driver for Android Studio, but Windows forces me to use the Samsung Mobile MTP Device driver. I am guessing this is the issue because Android Studio seems to require the Google USB driver:  `C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`. Is this truly the cause of the issue? If so, how can this be rectified? I prefer to use my own device when testing over an emulator.

Comment: @R2R I did try what was suggested: ensuring I am not defaulting to emulator and checking that my phone was in developer mode. Unfortunately, neither worked

Comment: What device are you using? AFAIK the Google USB driver is [only for Nexus and Pixel devices](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb.html)